# Concordance de temps. Dois-je faire une concordance ?

Tags: grammaire, concordance-des-temps

Imaginons que mon ami m'ait dit il y a un mois qu'il aurait une grève. Aujourd'hui je l'ai rencontré et lui ai dit qu'il avait eu raison.

Je lui ai dit :

> "Comme tu as dit la grève **commencera** / **commencerait** lundi
>   prochain."

En disant cela est-ce que je dois faire concorder la deuxième partie  de phrase « la grève commencera lundi prochain » avec « comme tu as dit » ?

Je pense que non et qu'elles sont indépendantes, n'est-ce pas ?

Est-ce que celle-ci est bonne ?

> Comme tu as dit la grève commencera lundi prochain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**C'est correct:**

> Comme tu l'as dit, la grève commencera demain.

Il n'y a pas de concordance entre les deux parties:

- la première est dans le passé. On pourrait aussi dire: *Comme tu l'avais dit*, ou *Comme tu le dis* (passé simple). Elle est à l'**affirmatif**.
- la seconde est dans le futur, et se déroulera (on en est sûr). On pourrait dire aussi *La grève va commencer demain*. Elle est aussi à l'**affirmatif**.

**L'autre forme est possible, si l'incertitude demeure:**

> Comme tu l'as dit, la grève commencerait demain (sous certaines conditions qui ne sont toujours pas certaines).

En revanche, si la seconde était une **proposition relative**, il faudrait une **dépendance**:

> Tu as dit que la grève commencera demain (si c'est certain).
>
> Tu as dit que la grève commence demain (idem).
>
> Tu as dit que la grève commencerait demain (incertain, si ...).

Answer (score 2):

Il y a un mois, la grève était une hypothèse, l'emploi du conditionnel était donc requis.

La rencontre de ce jour confirme une supposition, à savoir que la grève aura bien lieu lundi prochain, l'usage du futur de l'indicatif est donc correct.

> Comme tu l'as dit, la grève **commencera** lundi prochain.

Answer (score 1):

Il y a un mois, cet ami a dit, puisqu'il en était convaincu: « la grève commencera lundi prochain ».

Un mois plus tard, la grève a à priori déjà commencé puisque l'ami a eu raison. Ce fameux lundi n'est donc plus dans le futur et on ne peut plus le qualifier de prochain.

Une phrase qui confirme la justesse de la prévision en satisfaisant à cette contrainte peut donc être :

> Comme tu l'as dit, la grève a bien commencé lundi (ou aujourd'hui le cas échéant).

Si en revanche la grève n'a pas encore commencé, l'ami n'a pas pu dire il y a un mois « la grève commencera lundi prochain » mais quelque chose comme « il y aura bientôt une grève ». Il peut alors subsister une petite incertitude et l'on pourrait dire:

> Comme tu l'as dit, la grève devrait bien commencer lundi prochain.
>
> Comme tu l'as dit, la grève doit bien commencer lundi prochain.

Finalement, s'il ne fait aucun doute que la grève va avoir lieu:

> Comme tu l'as dit, la grève commencera lundi prochain.